# Tomcat7 rejecting POSTS when Expect header is empty

Tags: http, tomcat

Tomcat7 is responding to a curl POST with an explicit but empty Expect header with a 417 Expectation Failed.

```
curl -v -H "Expect;" <URL>
```

tomcat responds

```
> POST <...> HTTP/1.1
> Host: <...>
> User-Agent: curl/7.53.0
> Accept: */*
> Expect:
>
< HTTP/1.1 417 Expectation Failed
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

However, Tomcat6 accepted this POST.  I am obviously trying to upgrade to Tomcat7 but have products in the public domain (which cannot be modified) which always add these empty headers.

Is there a way to configure Tomcat7 to accept these empty Expect headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is NO way to config Tomcat7 and disable `Expect` header check. The only way to disable it is modifying Tomcat7's source code and rebuild your own version.

The related code is located in `apache-tomcat-7.0.75-src/java/org/apache/coyote/http11/AbstractHttp11Processor.java`:

```
    MessageBytes expectMB = null;
    if (http11) {
        expectMB = headers.getValue("expect");
    }
    if (expectMB != null) {
        if (expectMB.indexOfIgnoreCase("100-continue", 0) != -1) {
            getInputBuffer().setSwallowInput(false);
            expectation = true;
        } else {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_EXPECTATION_FAILED);
            setErrorState(ErrorState.CLOSE_CLEAN, null);
        }
    }
```

It appears there is no configuration option to disable `Expect` header check. To solve your problem, these code should be removed.

This behaviour of Tomcat7 is by design, to follow the HTTP standard. It is release in Tomcat 7.0.55 (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html): "If request contains an unrecognized Expect header, respond with error 417 (Expectation Failed), according to RFC2616 chapter 14.20. "

Comment: Hmmm, that would seem pretty conclusive.  Thanks, unfortunately I'm pretty sure our security team wouldn't allow for custom builds.  Time to find another way around it.